# package xxx.genexus.common does not exist compiling an Android application on Genexus 15 U4

Tags: genexus-sd

I have converted a KB from GX EV3 U11 to GX 15 U4 but there are errors during Android compilation.

> ========== DeveloperMenu Compilation for Android (Android) started ==========
>   callmake.bat "C:\KB\EncuestasMoviles15\CSharpModel\mobile\Android\gxcommon\GXAMake.exe" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac.exe" developermenu ec\com\inalambrik\encuestasmoviles\ options:
>   GeneXus Java Make v1.0
>   warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
>   ec\com\inalambrik\encuestasmoviles\sdsetsitesdistancefromlocation.java:64: error: package ec.com.inalambrik.encuestasmoviles.genexus.common does not exist
>      public void execute( ec.com.inalambrik.encuestasmoviles.genexus.common.SdtGeolocationInfo[] aP0 ,
>                                                                            ^
>   ec\com\inalambrik\encuestasmoviles\sdsetsitesdistancefromlocation.java:70: error: package ec.com.inalambrik.encuestasmoviles.genexus.common does not exist
>      private void execute_int( ec.com.inalambrik.encuestasmoviles.genexus.common.SdtGeolocationInfo[] aP0 ,
>                                                                                 ^
>   ec\com\inalambrik\encuestasmoviles\sdsetsitesdistancefromlocation.java:158: error: package ec.com.inalambrik.encuestasmoviles.genexus.common does not exist
>      private ec.com.inalambrik.encuestasmoviles.genexus.common.SdtGeolocation AV14geolocation ;
>                                                               ^
>   ec\com\inalambrik\encuestasmoviles\sdsetsitesdistancefromlocation.java:159: error: package ec.com.inalambrik.encuestasmoviles.genexus.common does not exist
>      private ec.com.inalambrik.encuestasmoviles.genexus.common.SdtGeolocationInfo[] aP0 ;
>   ...
>   ...

I think there is a problem with built in modules (maybe version or file location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this by making calls to clientinformation, clientstorage and geolocation API only on clientstart event.